# Estimating SQL database size

Tags: database, size, sql-server-2008-r2, estimation

We know there're [official estimation guides](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187445.aspx) how to estimate Microsoft SQL database size.

But since they use some formulae or types etc, such calculators could exists as an online service where you'd enter required data and you'd get an estimated results out of it.

Does anyone know of such a web site/service where things like that could be done?

Comment: why do you want to use a web site, when you can that in excel? Plus you get to version control the development artifact i.e the capacity planning spreadsheet.

Comment: @Mitch: That's fine just as well as long as you can point me to a such file somewhere that I could use as a starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Web: no
- Excel: [several](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=sql%20server%20database%20size%20estimator%20excel)

To be cynical, Excel is the best tool for the job because it's a series of calculations.

If I was a DBA why would I go for a web based tool when there is *zero* benefit for me? This isn't like a free salary calculator, for example, provided by a payrolling company who can offer you paid services too.

Comment: That is all true, but as you can find all kinds of *zero benefit* services on the web (as someone thinks they may help others as well) I thought there could be a web app for that as well. Thank you. I've done the same think few days ago using Excel as well.